# Uniform Scaling a Grouped Object, Shapes Move Out of Place or Distort. How can I fix this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

Here's my problem:

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 and I'm trying to scale a grouped object uniformly or proportionately but the shapes that make up the object move out of place. Here's what I'm looking at:

Before Scaling

[image: before]

After Scaling

[image: before]
[image: before]

The chicken coop is made up of individual triangles. I have grouped them and made sure that "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid" is turned off. Whenever I scale it smaller or larger, there are some triangles that move out place. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only reason I've seen paths move unexpectedly is of Align to Pixel Grid is on. I know you said it's off, but you may want to Select All, and then verify it's off, and not a hyphenated checkbox. A hyphenated checkbox means it's on for some objects and off for others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott. I just double checked and it's turned off. I did what you said, selected all, turned it on then turned it off. Same result. Is it possible that there might be another setting that's causing this?

Comment: Not really. The only other option would be you are enlarging and the paths were never really aligned to begin with. So, the enlargement is merely showing that misalignment more.

Comment: Okay, that was what I was thinking too, that they must not be aligned in the first place since most of the shapes are scaling correctly. I'll have to go over it again and make sure everything is properly aligned. Thanks for all your time and help, Scott. I appreciate it.

Comment: Check your General Preferences panel (Illustrator->Preferences->General) and look to see if (Scale Strokes & Effects) is checked or unchecked. This might be effecting the objects shifting as well.